# Proteção x Liberdade - Fontes Pagas

Tags: css

Sabemos que, quando um site resolve utilizar uma fonte paga em seu site, ele busca design e ao mesmo tempo diferenciação.

Mas, para que o utilizador veja a fonte em trabalho na página, o desenvolvedor deve de alguma maneira declarará para o cliente baixa-la para assim visualizar a fonte em comportamento.

Com isso, as fontes pagas acabam se tornando livre? Já que, de alguma maneira ela é exposta para apresentar ao cliente e permitir o navegador a exibi-lo em ação..

Ou ainda, existe técnicas para inibir que outras pessoas capturem essas fontes, talvez algo com Javascript, técnica HTTP para inibir outras hosts,...?

Comment: Posta um exemplo de site onde você não encontra a fonte.
isso vai tirar todas suas duvidas
http://imasters.com.br/artigo/20429/css/font-face-tipografia-sem-restricoes-na-web/

Comment: Vou ler, mas de antemão deixo aqui o site como exemplo, que pelo pesquisei é paga e não achei como pegar no site..

http://viverdeblog.com -> freight-sans-pro

Comment: http://goo.gl/myjO4z , basta aperta f12 e depois ctrl F + " freight-sans-pro", sua pergunta ta fora do escopo de programação.

Comment: Pelo visto este site utiliza uma URL para capturar a fonte, mas o erro é 403 ao acessar, talvez seja uma permissão que só o site tenha com ele e os visitantes.., como se fosse uma maneira para não pegarmos a fonte, só pode ser isso ao meu ver..

Comment: Estou com uma dúvida sobre a proteção das fontes pagas, isso envolve CSS e talvez até JavaScript para proteção da mesma com alguma técnica, porquê fora do escopo? Acho que deixei mal escrito meu tópico..